# navigator.online works in desktop but always returns true in my android phone

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I need to check if user is connected to the internet. My code works very well on browser but fails in android phone.

In `app.js`, I have the following code:

```
  $rootScope.online = navigator.onLine;
      $window.addEventListener("offline", function () {
        console.log("called offline")
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          $rootScope.online = false;

        });
      }, false);
      $window.addEventListener("online", function () {
        console.log("called online")
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          $rootScope.online = true;
        });
      }, false);
```

In app, The events are never really fired and navigator.onLine always returns true? How do I fix this?